# Can I move HERE maps logo and terms of use to the top on javasctipy API?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I would love to set the obligatory logo and terms of use to the top of the webview

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a closer look at [H.Map#getImprint](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map.html#h-map__getimprint) and the related [H.map.Imprint](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-imprint.html) class.

You can get a reference to the imprint's style via [H.map.Imprint#getStyle](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-imprint.html#h-map-imprint__getstyle) and then adjust that as necessary.

```js
// e.g. move imprint to the right
let imprintStyle = map.getImprint().getStyle();
imprintStyle.left = '';
imprintStyle.right = '0.5em';
```